# using counta in offset and dealing with cells with no value

Tags: excel

I am using offset to get a range of the last 7 entries in a column which updates automatically when I add data to it.  However, to be able to automate this as much as possible I have to use a formula to determine if there is a value to display in that cell. This causes the cell to be not-empty and thus the offset isn't working. Any workaround for this?

I copy the data from Sheet1 into another sheet because I need to hide the columns in Sheet1, and therefor can't create a sparkline for those values anymore.  Copying the data into column B on Sheet 2:

```
=IF(Sheet1!O18<>"";Sheet1!O18;"")
```

Using the offset:

```
=OFFSET(Sheet2!$B$3;COUNTA(Sheet2!$B:$B)-7;0;7)
```

Comment: I got it working with a workaround in the OFFSET;  I changed the formula on sheet2 to assign the value 0 in case of no-entry, and changed the OFFSET to COUNTA(Sheet2!$B:$B)-COUNTIF(Sheet2!$B:$B;0)-7  this works :)

Comment: Please post your answer as an answer, and then accept it to mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working with a workaround in the OFFSET; I changed the formula on sheet2 to assign the value 0 in case of no-entry, and changed the OFFSET to COUNTA(Sheet2!$B:$B)-COUNTIF(Sheet2!$B:$B;0)-7 this works :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `SUMPRODUCT` formula as described in this thread: [Excel - Create chart from range of cells while excluding null values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6592006/excel-create-chart-from-range-of-cells-while-excluding-null-values/6592480)
`=OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$2,1,0,SUMPRODUCT(IF(Sheet1!A2:A60<>"",1,0)),1))`